# What is the difference between option<t>=? and just =? in ReScript JSX?

Tags: bucklescript, rescript

From the documentation of ReScript React, I can declare a component like this:

```
module OptionalChildren = {
  @react.component
  let make = (~children: option<React.element>=?, ~children2: React.element=?) => {
    <div>
      {switch children {
      | Some(element) => element
      | None => React.string("No children provided")
      }}
      {switch children2 {
      | Some(element) => element
      | None => React.string("No children provided")
      }}
    </div>
  }
}
```

Both `children` and `children2` evaluate to `option<React.element>` type? So, what's the difference? Is latter just the short form of former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first form is explicit, since `children` will actually be an `option<_>`. The second form will emit the warning:

> React: optional argument annotations must have explicit `option`. Did you mean `option(React.element)=?`?

The word "must" is a bit odd, since clearly it does compile without it. But I believe the motivation for it is type annotation accuracy, to avoid confusion. For example, what if your intention is actually `option<option<React.element>>`? How would you interpret seeing just `option<React.element>`?

Note also that it's possible to provide a default argument, `~children: React.element=React.null` for example, which adds to the complexity of the construct.